# Vue Error compiling template - Unexpected colon when using v-attr

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a Vue component:

```
// Define a new component called tile
Vue.component('truchet-tile', {
  data: function() {
    return {ttype: 0};
  },
  computed: {
    // a computed getter
    image: function() {
      let filename;
      switch (ttype) {
        case 0:
          filename = "horizontal";
          break;
          [... snip ...]
        default:
          return "";
      }
      return 'http://mazes.doontoon.com/' + filename + '.svg';
    }
  },
  template: '<img v-attr="src:image" />'
});
```

I get this error:
[image: invalid expression: Unexpected token colon]

I have tried using `v-bind` or `{{ }}` to `src` instead, but that is not recommended: https://012.vuejs.org/api/directives.html#v-attr

[JSFiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/facechomp/gwe2f1ds/82/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `v-bind:src="image"` or for shortcut `:src="image"` direct without `v-attr`,

```
<!-- verbose -->
<img v-bind:src="url" />

<!-- shorthand -->
<img :src="url" />
```

and this your code:

```
// Define a new component called tile
Vue.component('truchet-tile', {
  data: function() {
    return {ttype: 0};
  },
  computed: {
    // a computed getter
    image: function() {
      let filename;
      switch (ttype) {
        case 0:
          filename = "horizontal";
          break;
          [... snip ...]
        default:
          return "";
      }
      return 'http://mazes.doontoon.com/' + filename + '.svg';
    }
  },
  template: '<img :src="image" />'
});
```

Also you add v0.12 link and use vuejs v2.5 in your fiddle example, so please check the latest updates from Vuejs and how it works now, [check this](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind)

Comment: I see what you mean. Does the tip/warning at [https://012.vuejs.org/api/directives.html#v-attr](https://012.vuejs.org/api/directives.html#v-attr) apply to `v-bind`, or only to `{{ }}`.

Comment: no in v2.5 only to normal or public attributes and there is [special attributes](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Special-Attributes), if you will using v-bind you will use it outside the `v-attr`